# SVG linear path animation using x,y coordinates only

Tags: javascript

This codepen is working fine when we need a close path or a polygon , i have set of x and y coordinates , i want to write a function that create the complete path based on the x and y coordinates . But how can we convert the x,y coordinates to what svg understands .

https://codepen.io/manabox/pen/MWQGxb

```
        <svg x="0px" y="0px" width="150px" height="145px" viewBox="0 0 148.9 140.8">
          <polygon points="65.7,0 0,64.4 34.9,69.8 30.9,140.8 67.1,138.2 67.1,96.6 87.2,95.2 91.2,140.8 127.4,132.8 
            120.7,75.1 148.9,69.8 116.7,40.2 122.1,4 99.3,1.3 99.3,22.8 "/>
        </svg>
```

CSS :

```
            svg polygon {
              fill: none;
              stroke: #09d;
              stroke-width: 3;
              stroke-dasharray: 1000;
              stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
              -webkit-animation: dash 5s linear forwards;
              animation: dash 5s linear forwards;
            }
            @-webkit-keyframes dash {
              to {
                stroke-dashoffset: 0;
              }
            }
            @keyframes dash {
              to {
                stroke-dashoffset: 0;
              }
            }
```

Comment: You can use a line group instead of a polygon tag [line tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/SVG/Element/line)

Answer (score 1):

You can easily concatenate coordinates for use with `<polyline>` or `<path>` elements.

#### Example 1: draw polyline from coordinate array

```js
let coords = [
  [0, 50],
  [20, 10],
  [40, 30],
  [60, 90],
  [80, 20],
  [100, 50]
];

polyline.setAttribute("points", coords.join(" "));
polyline.classList.add("animateLine");

range.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
  //remove animation to use dynamic dashoffset value
  polyline.classList.remove("animateLine");
  let val = +e.currentTarget.value;
  polyline.setAttribute("style", `stroke-dashoffset:${100 - val}`);
});
```

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: block;
  width: 75vmin;
}

polyline {
  stroke: red;
  stroke-width: 1px;
  fill: none;
  stroke-linecap: square;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.animateLine {
  animation: dash 1s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes dash {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <polyline id="polyline" pathLength="100" stroke-dasharray="100" stroke-dashoffset="100" />
</svg>
<p>Value: <input id="range" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" step="10"></p>
```

The above example joins all coordinates by a simple `coords.join(" ")` method.
To simplify the dash-offset animation we're applying [`pathLength="100"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/pathLength).
This way, a dash value (so either used for stroke-dashoffset or stroke-dasharray) of 100 always corresponds to the total length of our path – regardless of how long it actually is.

#### Example 2: convert coordinates to `<path>` d attribute

```js
let coords = [
  [0, 50],
  [20, 10],
  [40, 30],
  [60, 90],
  [80, 20],
  [100, 50]
];

path.setAttribute('d', 'M' + coords.join(' '));
adjustViewBox(svg);

path.classList.add('animateLine');

range.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  //remove animation to use dynamic dash value
  path.classList.remove('animateLine');
  let val = +e.currentTarget.value;
  path.setAttribute('style', `stroke-dasharray:${val} 100`)
})

function adjustViewBox(svg) {
  let bb = svg.getBBox();
  let [x, y, width, height] = [bb.x, bb.y, bb.width, bb.height];
  svg.setAttribute("viewBox", [x, y, width, height].join(" "));
}
```

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: block;
  width: 75vmin;
}

path {
  stroke: red;
  stroke-width: 1px;
  fill: none;
  stroke-linecap: square;
  stroke-dasharray: 0 100;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.animateLine {
  animation: dash 1s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes dash {
  to {
    stroke-dasharray: 100 100;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <path id="path" pathLength="100" stroke-dasharray="100"  />
</svg>
<p>Value: <input id="range" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" step="10"></p>
```

```
path.setAttribute('d', 'M' + coords.join(' '));
```

We need to prepend a 'M' (starting point command) to the `d` attribute string.

The above example changes the stroke-dasharray from:

```
stroke-dasharray=0 100" // 0 %
```

to

```
stroke-dasharray="100 100" // 100 %
```

No need for a dashoffset – the first dasharray value is the current progress; the second your gap size (just leave it at 100 units)

If your coordinate array is highly dynamic you might need some method to adjust the svg `<viewBox>` to the currently rendered data.